# Getting variables that is created from another class

Tags: java, android

I have some problem getting the variables that I have created from another class.

This is the data I am retrieving it from.

```
public class Data{

    private String mName;

    public Data(String sometext){
    this.mName = sometext;
    }

    public String getmName(){
    return mName;
    )
```

Below is the main.

```
public class Class1 extends Fragment{

    private Data mData;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInsatanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);

    mData = new Data("Someone Name")
    .
    .
    .
```

This is the problem, from class Data2 i am not able to retrieve the variable i have created from Class1.

```
public class Data2{

    private Data notworking;

    public Data2(){
        notworking.mName;          //not working, reference to null
        notworking.getmName        // this is also not working, reference to null
    }
```

I cannot create a new Data because it will be a new object. Both of this reference to null. Is there other way to access the object I have created without using the public variable.

Added. picture for better understanding
[picture illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPWYi.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. You want to get information of your Data object inside a new object Data2 ? (Then pass the Data inside the constructor of Data2)

Comment: Yes, I need information from Data in order for my Data2 to process it. So that my Class2 can get the information of Data and Data2.

Comment: Can you show us where Data2 is created ? Seems like you have missed a step

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is assign the variable "notworking" in the Data2 class to the Data object "mData" you created in Class1.

An easy way to accomplish this is to have a Data2 constructor that takes a Data object as a parameter, and then assign notworking to that parameter.

```
public class Data2 {
    private Data notworking;

    public Data2(Data dataObject){
        notworking = dataObject;
    }

    // getter method necessary since "notworking" is private
    public Data getNotworking() {
        return notworking;
    }

}
```

Obviously, you need a Data2 variable in your Class1. Then you just construct your Data2 object and pass in "mData".

```
mData2 = new Data2(mData);
```